# Optimal memory allocation for Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Apache Spark on a 32 core system with 244GB memory. I am running a tree based algorithm where I am required to grow separately 500 trees. What should be my optimal spark setting in this context when I have a process which can be parallelized into 500 processes

I am quite new to spark and the implications of `spark.driver.memory`, `spark.executor.memory` and `spark.driver.maxResultSize` are not exactly clear to me. But it seems from documentations these variables are key to optimizing allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can allocate static resources to you applications

Your total cluster resources are
Total cores 32 
Total RAM 244 GB

First 1 core and 1 GB should be allocated for the OS leaving 243 GB RAM and 33 Cores

Core is the concurrency level in Spark so as you have 33 cores you can have 33 concurrent processes running simultaneously.

Next come the calculation for the number of executors. Each executor run in its own JVM process and each Worker node can run multiple executors. This is recommended that each executor should have at most 5 concurrent processes otherwise contention amount concurrent processes will be not be manageable in a single JVM instance. So you need to run multiple executors on a single Worker node.   33 / 5 = 6.6  and rounding it to 6     So there can be 6 Executors

dividing 243 GB of RAM in 6 executors will be  40.5  rounding it to 40 GB for each executor

So in your case the you will set following properties

```
Number of cores for each executor = 5
Number of Executors = 6
RAM = 40 GB
```

Now comes to your other question which is the purpose of following properties 
**spark.driver.memory** is the memory needed to run driver process. As we left some memory while rounding off there is plenty of memory for driver

**spark.executor.memory**  we calculated as 40 GB for each executor above.  This is the memory available for each executor

**spark.driver.maxResultSize**  and this is the max size once the spark job is run and results are return to the driver. If we set this to 1 GB and return results are greater than 1 GB then we may get out of memory exception.